# Octopus deploy error Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error converting value "Canceled"

Tags: teamcity, octopus-deploy

All of sudden my octopus deploy is failing for only a particular project. Everything was working fine but not sure why i keep getting this error. Builds successfully in Teamcity.

[image]
Can anyone please help me diagnose what could be the issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug with Octopus and Teamcity, when a unhandled error occurs on the O.D side, Teamcity cannot handle the error and shows up as "*Error converting value Canceled*'"

It may build fine on the Teamcity side, **always** double check on the Octopus deploy side.

A very good chance a deploy failed due to an error that is not handled, i.e, an exception, a condition that failed within a step in the process.